# Is Aegir drupal 8 compatible?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, aegir

I don't find a clear answer on that matter.
Can Aegir ( current 3.3 version ) work with drupal 8 sites ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Absoultely, we have a lot of test D8 sites on Aegir 3.3 (we have a free SaaS service to test Drupal 8, based on Aegir).

More generally, Aegir3 supports Drupal 8 since 3.1 I believe, and we wouldn't release a version that would break Drupal 8 support (I'm a maintainer of Aegir).

Comment: does aegir 3+ support both deployments of d7 and d8?

Comment: Absolutely. A lot of effort went into Drupal 8 recently. You can totally have both on the same server (from an Aegir perspective at least).

Comment: thanks @gboudrias - I have it as a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42682279/does-aegir-3-support-both-d7-and-d8-deployments if you'd like credit

Comment: "Is Aegir drupal 8 compatible?" Answer: "Absoultely..." But given that https://www.drupal.org/project/hostmaster is only Drupal 7 does this limit the functionality for Drupal 8 sites. In other words should there be a Drupal 8 version of hostmaster?

Comment: In Aegir 3, the Drupal front-end (hostmaster) is Drupal 7, correct, but that doesn't in any way limit which sites it can manage.  In fact, Aegir 5's front-end will be Drupal 8, but it will be able to manage non-Drupal sites.  Basically, it doesn't matter what the front-end site is built with.