# Does Aegir 3+ support both D7 and D8 deployments

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-8, aegir

We have a current installation of Aegir, old enough to not support D8 installs. Looking to cut over at some point. So that begs the question:

Does Aegir 3+ support both Drupal 7 and Drupal 8 installations? To where we could deploy a D7 test site to a D7 server and likewise with 8 from the same Aegir interface?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Aegir drupal 8 compatible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35267828/is-aegir-drupal-8-compatible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does Aegir 3+ support both Drupal 7 and Drupal 8 installations?

Yes.

> To where we could deploy a D7 test site to a D7 server and likewise with 8 from the same Aegir interface?

Yes.

Drupal 8 has been supported since the version first 3.x version and refined ever since. Check out the [official docs](http://docs.aegirproject.org) for more info.

Comment: Thank you for this. We have started our D8 roadmap and will use this to help us make the transition, while still supporting D7 sites.